# What are appropriate execution permissions for ~/bin?

Tags: linux, permissions

I am putting some scripts in ~/bin and am wondering what appropriate file permissions are. To extend my question somewhat, what permissions make sense for */bin folders all over my system, and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually:

- they are writable by the owner (root for `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, ...)
- they executable and readable by everyone else

But your question should instead be:

- who should be able to modify the directory?
- who should be able to read the content and execute the binaries?

Once you answer these questions the permissions are straightforward.

An *example*:

```
$ ls -ld /bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin ${HOME}/bin
drwxr-xr-x     8 corti  corti    272 Apr 11  2011 /Users/corti/bin
drwxr-xr-x    39 root   wheel   1326 Jul 21 19:37 /bin
drwxr-xr-x   948 root   admin  32232 Oct 10 08:36 /opt/local/bin/
drwxr-xr-x  1205 root   wheel  40970 Oct  5 09:01 /usr/bin
```